# Changing the preview image when sharing a news article on Facebook?

Tags: web-apps, facebook, sharing, social-networks, saas

I want to share an external link (news article) to my company's Facebook page, but the thumbnail is just a generic image showing the name of the news site, so it looks like I'm advertising the newspaper. Is there a web-app or browser extension that allows me to change the preview image to something more relevant to the topic of the article?

[image]